# How do I read and process a file in a separate method and call it in the main method in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, try-catch

I have this code i'm working on to compute the ARI of a given text read from the a .txt file. This code works perfectly but I want to put in fewer things in my main method. How is it able to put my try and catch block in a new method and then call it to my main method instead of having everything mashed together? I have tried some few ways but i'm not getting the usual output.

Here is my main class:

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String EachSentence;
    int wordCount;

    List<Sentence> sentences = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> EachWordCount = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> EachLetterCounted= new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        File file = new File("a2b.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        scanner.useDelimiter("[.?!]");
        int SentenceCount =0;
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            SentenceCount++;
            EachSentence = scanner.next();
            EachSentence = EachSentence.replaceAll("\\r?\\n", " ");
            EachSentence = EachSentence.trim();
            if (sentences.add(new Sentence(EachSentence)) && sentences.size() > 1){
                System.out.println("(" + SentenceCount + ") " + EachSentence);
            }
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(EachSentence, " ");
            wordCount = tokenizer.countTokens();
            if(EachWordCount.add(wordCount)&& EachWordCount.size() > 1){
                //I removed the element at position 0 so as to correlate with EachSentence then added the counts to the arrayList
                //to prepare them for addition
                EachWordCount.remove(0);
                EachWordCount.add(wordCount);
            }
            int LetterCount=1;
            for(int i=1; i<EachSentence.length(); i++){
                char currentChar = EachSentence.charAt(i);
                if(currentChar != ' '&& currentChar!='('&&currentChar!=')'&&currentChar!=','&& currentChar!='.'){
                    EachLetterCounted.add(LetterCount);
                    LetterCount++;
                }
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    }catch (IOException ex){ 
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }


    //Computes the ARI of the total sentences
    double lettersCounted = (double) lettersCounted(EachLetterCounted);
    double wordsCounted = (double) sum(EachWordCount);
    double sentencesCounted = (double) SentencesCounted(EachWordCount);
    double AutomatedReadabilityIndex= 4.71*(lettersCounted/wordsCounted) + 0.5 * (wordsCounted/sentencesCounted) -21.43;

    System.out.println("\nSummary statistics: ");
    System.out.println("Letters: "+lettersCounted(EachLetterCounted));

    System.out.println("Words: "+ sum(EachWordCount));
    System.out.println("Sentences: " + SentencesCounted(EachWordCount));

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    System.out.println("readability: "+ df.format(AutomatedReadabilityIndex));
}
```

contributions would be great!

Comment: I will not tell you have to do it, but I will give you hint to send you on your way: When refactoring, try to isolate pieces of code that are depending on each other tightly, operate on the same data and are strongly related. Put those pieces into function. And have that function return the final value of the function on the exact same place where the code used to be.

Refactoring is like breaking stuff apart, for example car.You can break car two distinct part: engine and chassis.Then of course you can break apart engine,into cylinders and ignition. But would cylinders work without ignition?

Comment: I see what you're trying to accomplish, truth of the matter is it all depends on how you think the code should flow. Do you want to make the File and Scanner objects global and initialize them in main? Do you want to perhaps do the initialization and processing of the File in a separate method? Do you want to pass the File as an argument to a method? It's up to you. But in general, there should be a "feel" of what goes together, you should encapsulate that in a method. Maybe different files get read at times, then you'd want to have a method that takes in a file, etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to comment. I found a way to solve it @TheLaw

Comment: okay, noted. Thanks @Ceelos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second time answering my question.(For anyone having the same problem) I achieved this by simply putting everything I had in the main method in a `...static void ReadFile()` method and calling only `ReadFile in the main method. It may not be the best way but it was what I was looking for :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReadFile();
}

public static void ReadFile() {
   //insert all what is in main method, the exceptions were handled
   //here also. So there was no need for the throws IOException that 
   //should've followed.
}
```

OR

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReadFile(//insert name of file to be read here);
}

public static void ReadFile(String filename) {
   //insert all what is in main method, the exceptions were handled
   //here also. So there was no need for the throws IOException that 
   //should've followed.
}
```

Comment: Replace StringTokenizer  with String.split ()